# PHP and MySQL: Least resource intensive method to serve images as data URI's: Storing base64 encoding in mysql or base64_encode with PHP from file?

Tags: php, mysql, base64, data-uri

I would like to serve images as DATA URI's using base64 encoding. I found two methods:

1. Store base64 encoding in the database, retrieve and insert as `src` for image.
2. Store in file system, and have PHP `data64_encode()` the image every time and insert the string into `src`.

What would be the least resource intensive method, or preferable for other reasons?

Comment: I think 2 posts are helpful: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585708/how-to-export-a-base64-string-to-a-file-on-server-side-without-saving-it-in-we
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700069/how-to-read-a-base64-string-as-a-file-on-server-side-without-saving-it-in-web?rq=1 Good luck!

Comment: ... and it's clearly not network bandwidth!

Comment: How about this option: `3. Store base64 encoding in the file system, retrieve and insert as src for image.`