# How to export a Base64 string to a file, on server side, without saving it in web server, directly by PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, base64

I am using **PHP** and **MySQL** for my programming.

---

I have stored some **Base64** strings (which are encoded from files). I know that `base64_decode();` can decode **Base64** strings to files.

Now, I want to decode these **Base64** strings to files, by **PHP**, without saving it in my **web server**; but, **web browser** can **download** it from **web link** (http://example.com/save.php?fileid=23413).

In my **PHP** page, http://example.com/save.php?fileid=23413, I did:

1. I can use `echo();` for printing Base64 strings. So, there is no problem with my **MySQL** queries.
2. I have delete `echo();` from my **PHP** page.
3. I tried to use `base64_decode();` to decode **Base64** strings to files. I want when I nagivate to this page, it will export a file. But, It returns an **empty** page.

---

Can you help me to decode **Base64** strings to files, by **PHP**, without saving it in my **web server**, and **web browser** can **download** it from **web link** (http://example.com/save.php?fileid=23413)?

Comment: can you post your actual code where the problem lies.

Comment: You are overcomplicating this issue focusing on actual content of output. You just need to output with headers like any streaming file output.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding headers to the script before echoing the output

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= ".$file."");
echo base64_decode($file);
```

Comment: Also, it is always better for the browser/client if  `content-size` is provided (when possible).